# How do I access $_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET inside Magento CE modules?

Tags: magento-1.7

How do I access $_REQUEST, $_POST or $_GET inside Magento CE modules?
When I try they all return nothing, so where did the $_REQUEST data disappear to?

Comment: Elaborate with some code you had tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a controller use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name',default value);
```

Anywhere else use:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('param_name',default value);
```

Magento provides a few methods to retrieve GET, POST and Request globals. All these methods are present in the request class:

```
Zend_Controller_Request_Http
```